# Setting for <? and <?php

Tags: php

I am running 5.2.14. Starting php code code using `<?` does not work. I must use `<?php`

For example:

Does not work:

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

Does work:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Where can I change this setting so `<?` will work?

Comment: Don't, if you want your code to run on servers where you can't fiddle with the ini.

Comment: @Visitor, always use `<?php`.  It is only a few more characters that you need, and as delnan said, if you want your code to work everywhere without hassle, you need it.

Comment: Not only that, but it makes it completely insane to work with anything that uses <?'s like xml documents.

Comment: Might as well start using ASP syntax `<% %>`.  Which also sucks.

Comment: could even use <script type="text/php"></script> no wait..... thats longer

Answer (score 7):

edit yout php.ini file, and set `short_open_tag = On`

you can view the php.ini's path by runing `phpinfo();` function...

but, you can just write your scripts starting with `<?php`

Mike ;]

Comment: But note that this tends to make it more difficult to create PHP scripts that have an XML preamble at the top. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` needs to be printed with `echo` manually if you have `<? ?>` PHP tags allowed.

Comment: On the other hand, the XML preamble is basically useless :p

Answer (score 2):

It is best not to use the short tag `<?` in place of the normal `<?php`. If you ever need to host on a server that doesn't support editing the PHP configuration, it is a pain to find and replace the short tags with the standard ones.

From http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php:

> Tells PHP whether the short form (`<?
>   ?>`) of PHP's open tag should be
>   allowed. If you want to use PHP in
>   combination with XML, you can disable
>   this option in order to use 
>   inline. Otherwise, you can print it
>   with PHP, for example: <`?php echo
>   '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?`>. Also, if
>   disabled, you must use the long form
>   of the PHP open tag (`<?php ?>`).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as mishunika says change your php.ini file though be warned, if moving to another server later on it might not work. If you don't have access to the php.ini file on the other server you'll have to change them over to

`<?php`

Any reason you don't want to use the long tag?

Answer (score -1):

I agree with everyone in regards to using short tags. You should for compatibility reasons stay away from short tags. However, there are situations which may call for it. For example, if you are trying to use a PHP script that someone else wrote that uses short tags, then you can either modify the code or enable short_open_tag.

If you do not have writable access to the php.ini file (shared hosting) you may be able to set the flag using the PHP function "ini_set". You can read up on the function here:

[PHP ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

There are some flags and variables you cannot set with ini_set. I haven't personally tried to set the short_open_tag. Give it a shot.